# GAE, can't get PHP to work

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I need to set up a simple page on GAE, this is for someone who wants free hosting, basically. The page has a contact form, and I wrote a script in PHP. Ie: index.html, form action calls contact.php. Although placing the code on the index.html and calling that instead produced no results, anyway.

I can't figure out how to make PHP work on GAE. I tried changing the app.yaml settings several times, and either PHP is not recognized at all (even something simple like

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

produces no results) or the browser tries to force download the script.

Here's my current/last app.yaml:

```
application: [myappidentifier]
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /contact.php*
  script: contact.php

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|svg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|svg|ico|js|css))
```

I'm sure this is all my fault, somehow. :)
How can I fix this so PHP works as intended on GAE?

Thank you for your time.

---

EDIT: Well, nix the PHP mail() approach, they've disabled it on GAE, it seems?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/

But still, PHP in general doesn't seem to be working with my current setup.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unnecessary * in your handler for contact.php, try changing it to:

```
- url: /contact.php
  script: contact.php
```

Also, the more common way of working on AppEngine, it not to use file extensions for scripts, so change your handler to:

```
- url: /contact
  script: contact.php
```

And then change your links and form destinations to **/contact** instead of **/contact.php**

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! As I had mentioned, the yaml I posted was my last attempt, I saw someone using something similar and tried it out. Unfortunately, I have already tried the suggestions you made, and there was no result. I spent over 6 hours reading the documentation and scouring Google for answers, but nothing seems to work. If I place a simple echo statement on the index.html it isn't recognized as PHP and actually appears on the source code. From the PHP script, it produces a blank page. So it's like it's not being recognized as PHP. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If you put PHP code inside a .html file then no, it will not be recognised as PHP by AppEngine, that will only happen when the file is specified using the __script:__ directive, in your app.yaml file the .html file is specified as a static file.

Comment: For the .php file, if you are getting a blank page, this normally indicates some kind of PHP error, can you take a look in the AppEngine  logs and see if there are any entries relating to that file?

Comment: I see, I'm used to being able to set HTML files to be treated as PHP. I will try setting it as script. As for the log files, you're right! There was a small concatenation oversight that was causing an error. It seems to be working now, thank you very much for your help!